# Delphi Android compile Error : keytool.exe exited with code 3

Tags: java, delphi

i have problem while trying to compile program with android platform in my delphi
i use Delphi 10.3 Community Edition
and the error code is this

```
[Exec Error] The command ""\bin\KeyTool.exe" -genkey -v -keystore "C:\Users\Reza Fahlevi\AppData\Roaming\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\debug.keystore" -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -dname "cn=Unnamed, ou=Mobile Organization, o=Embarcadero Technologies, l=San Francisco, s=California, c=US" -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000" exited with code 3.
```

i tried to reinstalled JAVA but the problem is not gone, is there a way to fix this issue?
Thank you in advance

Comment: @AntonioPetricca yes it does.. and how to close this thread?

Comment: It will be closed after reaching 3 closing requests.

Comment: @AntonioPetricca alright. and thank you

Comment: The path to the Java home seems to be missing.